# Matplotlib tight_layout suboptimal result

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am too stupid for matplotlib's `tight_layout`, I think. Consider the code and result below. That the tickslabels of the right plot are cut off doesn't bother me that much. Rather, why is the left plot not placed right at the left edge (which would allow the right plot to grow larger)? How can I achieve that, without messing around with calculating the positions manually?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from math import ceil
%matplotlib notebook
w, h = 8,5
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(w, h), width_ratios=[3,1])
fig.patch.set_facecolor('xkcd:mint green')
data = np.random.random((50,2))
inf_val = 1
ax1.set_aspect('equal')
ax1.tick_params(left=False, labelleft=False, bottom=False, labelbottom=False)
ax1.set_xlim(np.min(data[:,0]), np.max(data[:,0]))
ax1.set_ylim(np.min(data[:,1]), np.max(data[:,1]))
ax2.set_aspect('equal')
ax2.set_xlim(0, 1)
ax2.set_ylim(0, 1)
fig.tight_layout(pad=0)

ax1.scatter(*data.T)
ax2.scatter(*data.T)
```

[image]